# How to create new object and assign it to pointer variable in a loop in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I'm a newbie in C++ and I don't understand what is causing my problem and how to fix it. Basically, I'm trying to create a stack of structs containing objects, but the program keeps giving me problems which I don't understand and can't fix. Any hint on what should I do would be much appreciated. My current error is:  `error: cannot convert ‘Telefon’ to ‘Telefon*’ in assignment`

```
class Telefon {
    public:
        Telefon() : cena(0.0), model(NULL), producent(NULL) {}
        double cena;
        string model;
        string producent;
    Telefon(double a, string b, string c) {
    cena=a;
    model=b;
    producent = c;
        }
};


Telefon* buildTelefon() {
   double cena;
   string model, producent;
   std::cout<< "podaj cene telefonu: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> cena;
   std::cout<< "podaj model telefonu: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> model;
   std::cout<< "podaj producenta telefonu: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> producent;
   Telefon *tel = new Telefon();
   tel = Telefon(cena, model, producent);
   return tel;

}


class StackLinkedList
{
  private:
  struct Node
{
    Telefon telefon;
    struct Node *ptrToNext;
};

  public:
         struct Node *first;
      StackLinkedList(){first = NULL;}
      void push(Telefon&);
};

void StackLinkedList::push(Telefon& telefon_)
{
    Node *oldfirst = first;
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->telefon = telefon_;
    temp->ptrToNext = oldfirst;
    first = temp;
}

int main () {
    int n;
    std::cout << "stacks length: "<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    StackLinkedList myStack = StackLinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        Telefon *telefon = buildTelefon();
        myStack.push(*telefon);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly are the problems you have?

Comment: Why are you messing with raw pointers and `new`?

Comment: First of all you should post your error messages here.

Comment: In genuine C++11 you should prefer smart pointers to raw pointers.

Comment: I'm sorry, just added the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you should replace

```
Telefon *tel = new Telefon();
tel = Telefon(cena, model, producent);
```

with

```
Telefon *tel = new Telefon(cena, model, producent);
```

or even better (in more [genuine](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) C++11).

```
auto tel = new Telefon(cena, model, producent);
```

But you should take days to read a good book on [Programming - Principles and practice using C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) and look on [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) anything you don't understand well.

Your code looks buggy and smells bad. Learn more about standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). Be sure to code for C++11 at least (so `NULL` is wrong, or at least very bad taste; use `nullptr`).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler). Improve your code till you get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`), notably to run your program step by step (and query the program state).

PS. If your compiler does not support C++11, you should upgrade or change your compiler. The C++11 standard has a lot of improvements w.r.t. older standards like C++03, and you should not lose your time learning something older than C++11.

Comment: This solution gives me `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: You need to take days to read more about C++. Then use the debugger.

Comment: `auto tel = new Telefon(cena, model, producent);` gives `error: ‘tel’ does not name a type`

Comment: You forgot to use a C++11 compiler (e.g. your compiler is too old). Perhaps you need to pass some flag like `-std=c++11` to your compiler.

Comment: it gives me `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
` anyway, but thank you for your reply.

Comment: Time to spend several days reading more about C++ and learning to use the debugger.

Comment: Oh, the problem was actually in assigning NULL value to string in `class Telefon` default constructor; thank you very much for your help